# Determine Generic type with recursive call

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a method that has two arguments:

```
public <P, T> T getT(P p, Class<T> returnType) {
    //This method converts p to an instance of the type T.
}
```

More or less, the code goes over all setters of the returnType and calls the getter method on the p:

```
T t = new T();
t.setBla(p.getBla());
```

Now, while looping over all setters of the T class, I come across a Collection. I want to recursively recall its own method for each item in the Collection.
My problem is, that I can't specify the return type since I can't figure out the return type of the Collection I receive. Something like this (pseudocode without reflection):

```
for(Object o : list) {
    return getT(o, ???);
}
```

I tried solving it with a custom annotation where I specifiy the returnType of that collection, but I can't use generics in my Annotation:

```
public @interface ReturnType {
    public Class<?> value();
}
```

So my argument in my getT() doesn't match. How can I fix this without changing my generic type of the getT() method (getT(P p, Class t))?

Answer (score 1):

If you can specify your generic as an extention of another class, you can instead write something like this:

```
public <P, T> T getT(P p, Class<T extends SomeClass> returnType){
//code
}
```

then

```
for(Object o : list) {
return getT(o, SomeClass.class);
}
```

and

```
public @interface ReturnType { 
public Class<SomeClass> value();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I realised this as well, but I can't use this unfortunatly. I was however able to solve my problem, but I haven't had time yet to post my solution yet. On top of that, I want to see what other people think before I post my solution :).